# Not able to pass application context in singleton class?

Tags: android, singleton

I have an app in which I made a singleton class which fetch `AdvertId`. But I am not able to pass `Application` context. How do I do that please check my code and guide me as well?

> Singleton class code:-

```
private static AdIdFetcher ourInstance = null;
public static Context context;
private static String TAG = AdIdFetcher.class.getSimpleName();

interface AdIdFetcherResult {
    void onId(String advertId);
}

public AdIdFetcher(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public static AdIdFetcher getOurInstance() {
    if (ourInstance == null) {
        ourInstance = new AdIdFetcher(context);
    }
    return ourInstance;
}

public void fetchId(final AdIdFetcherResult rcb) {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info id_Info = null;
            try {
                id_Info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
            } catch (IOException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String advertId = null;
            try {
                assert id_Info != null;
                advertId = id_Info.getId();
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement Id::::" + advertId);

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rcb.onId(advertId);
            return advertId;
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

> Calling class code:-

```
 AdIdFetcher.getOurInstance().fetchId(new AdIdFetcher.AdIdFetcherResult() {
        @Override
        public void onId(String advertId) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Advert ID:::"+advertId);
        }
    });
```

> Logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
```

Comment: where in your code you are setting the context? `public AdIdFetcher(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}` are you creating object of AdIdFetcher using above constructor before calling getOurInstance

Comment: That's what i want to set

Comment: at this line:- id_Info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass Context while calling `getOurInstance()`

```
public static AdIdFetcher getOurInstance(Context context) {
    if (ourInstance==null){
        ourInstance=new AdIdFetcher(context);
    }
    return ourInstance;
}
```

And call this as,

```
AdIdFetcher.getOurInstance(context).fetchId(new AdIdFetcher.AdIdFetcherResult() {
        @Override
        public void onId(String advertId) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Advert ID:::"+advertId);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping context as a static field causes memory leaks and is bad , you should not do that , instead pass the context in the `fetchId` method itself.

```
public void fetchId(Context context, final AdIdFetcherResult rcb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your calling code is in Activity or any Fragment right??

1. In case of Fragment:

   pass context in "getOurInstance()" like this:

   ```
   AdIdFetcher.getOurInstance(getActivity()).fetchId(.....
   ......
   ```
2. In case of Activity:

   pass context in "getOurInstance()" like this:

   ```
   AdIdFetcher.getOurInstance(classname.this).fetchId(.....
   ......
   ```

and in singleton class pass like this:

```
public static AdIdFetcher getOurInstance(Context context) {
  if (ourInstance==null){
    ourInstance=new AdIdFetcher(context);
  }
  return ourInstance;
}
```

and problem with your code is, you are getting context in constructor but never called that constructor in calling activity.